# AIML bot cannot find config folder in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, aiml

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms application and I'm trying to implement an AIML bot based on this tutorial: https://www.effacestudios.com/how-to-create-artificial-intelligence-chatbot/. I've added all the references and I've added a config and aiml folder into my directory. This is the code for when a button is clicked:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string settingsPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, Path.Combine("config", "Settings.xml"));
            string otherPath = @"C:/Users/PAVILION/Desktop/AimlTest/AimlTest/AimlTest/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/config/Settings.xml";
            Bot AI = new Bot();

            AI.loadSettings(otherPath);
            AI.loadAIMLFromFiles();
            AI.isAcceptingUserInput = false;

            User myuser = new User("User1", AI);
            AI.isAcceptingUserInput = true;
            Request r = new Request(UserEntry.Text, myuser, AI);
            Result res = AI.Chat(r);
            BotEntry.Text = "Tutorial Bot: " + res.Output;
        }
    }
```

Any time I input text into the Entry and tap the button I get an `Unable to find specified file` on the `loadSettings();`. I believe the function is looking for a Settings.xml and even though I've directed it to the exact file it still cannot be found. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are referencing local directory, for bot config. You must embed your file in project as resource.

Comment: @Adlorem Embed it as resource? Please how can I do this?

Comment: You need to embed  your config file in your shared project, or add it as resource file to Android project and iOS project, then load xml directly from compiled app. Another solution is to load config file from remote location. Anyway referencing config file from your local drive wont work.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and its still not working, it still gives me the error of "Unable to find specified file"

Comment: Please provide your code for additional help.

Comment: I have put the project in a rar, if this can help: https://www72.zippyshare.com/v/hQyYkQy4/file.html

Comment: I couldn't download the file from the link you post ,could you please upload your project in this website: https://github.com/   ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decompile aiml dll and then change loadsetting path to constant environment.specialfolder.loadapplication.
make sure you have placed your all required file there first.